# Insert React component after page load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React page build with data coming from a backend. Once the page is loaded, I have to perform some checks. If everything is OK then I need to add a component for ad purposes. This component needs to be added after the second paragraph of the page for example. An extra piece of information: I receive the markup from the backend. So I can't just add a conditional rendering somewhere and iterate on a state.

I can't manage to find a way to insert a component after page load. Is it even possible?

Comment: Why don't you keep a state as flag to show/hide your component and toggle its value after backend call? see conditional rendering here https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Along with conditional rendering, [React.Lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) can be used to load the component dynamically.

Comment: @Vishnu Can't really do that. I get the whole markup from the backend. So I have to inject the component between paragraphs after